# Linear extension from $c_0$ to $c$ has norm $\geq$ 2

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

By $c_0$ we denote the space of all real sequences that converge to $0$ and by $c$ the space of all real convergent sequences.   I need to show that any linear map $T:c\to c_0$ such that $T|_{c_0}$ is the identity has a norm at least 2.

A hint is given: Show that every closed ball in $c_0$ that contains $M=\{x\in c_0\mid ||x-1||\leq 1\}$ has a radius of at least 2.

I have already shown that hint, but I can't see how this helps.

I would appreciate a tip. Hopefully I can do the rest.

Comment: I found the solution now.

Comment: I suggest you post it, so that the question has an answer.